# Outlook: How to copy a hyperlink embedded in email?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, hyperlink

Thunderbird and other email clients include a right-click "Copy Link Location" menu item to allow one to copy the target of an embedded hyperlink to the clipboard.

This functionality appears to be sadly and conspicuously missing from Microsoft Outlook 2003. Does anyone know of a way to copy an embedded hyperlink without having to resort to visiting the site (by clicking on the link).

Comment: Strange if I do it in Outlook 2007 it gives me the options: Copy, Select/Open/Copy hyperlink and Who is ...

Comment: @Ivo too bad I'm stuck with '03 for the foreseeable future. Maybe I should try to get them to enable IMAP access so I can just use Thunderbird instead.

Answer (score 9):

1. Hit Reply/Forward
2. Right click on the URL>> Edit Hyperlink
3. Copy the link from the Address Textbox.

Comment: In a picture's case: (Office 2010), select 'Insert' > 'HyperLink'

Comment: @UjjwalSingh this is great, to select an image without activating the link you can right click it then cancel out of the context menu

Comment: This was necessary for me, because for a certain URL, right-clicking always visited the link.

Answer (score 4):

If you right click the link you should get a Properties option at the bottom.  If you select that you should then get a dialog box that has the link and you should be able to copy and paste it from there.

Paul

Comment: "Properties" is always grayed-out for me. In fact, only "Select All" and "View Source" are NOT grayed-out in the right-click menu...everything else is.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's ugly, but if you can click "View source" you can find the link in there as text, which you should most certainly be able to copy.

Comment: Yeah, I have done this occasionally, but the amount of friction involved is massive compared to what a simple "Copy Link Target" would allow.

Answer (score 1):

None of the other suggestions worked for me, I had to "Save as..." the mail, open it with an editor, find the appropriate hyperlink and then copy the corresponding href value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Outlook 2010 and when I open the email I have an option on the top of the "from" band that says:

"If there is a problem with how this message is displayed, click here to view it in a web browser"

I clicked on it, went to the browser, right-clicked on the image and selected Copy Shortcut.

Answer (score -1):

I found that scrappythenell's answer (Sep 19, 2011) really helped. AOL email (accessed via AOL Desktop, not their web mail) offers NO right-click option to copy a link target. I hated having to open the AOL browser (IE-based) to view and copy a hyperlink within my mail.  So, now I can do the following, and get an URL from an AOL email hyperlink.

### How to Copy Hyperlinks in AOL Emails

1. Hit the Forward email button.
2. In the window appearing with the editable text/images to forward, find the stand-in text or image for the hyperlink you want to copy.
3. Highlight it.
4. Right-click on the highlighted stand-in text or image.
5. From the Right-Click Menu options, select Edit Hyperlink.
6. Copy the link from the Address Textbox that appears.
7. Navigate over to your Firefox browser, right-click in the Firefox address box, and select Paste/Go.

The URL will appear in the address box and Firefox will go directly to the URL, depending upon any further permissions to allow navigation.  This method avoids having to open your AOL browser (IE) first just to get a viable URL to copy and paste to your preferred browser.

NOTE: Do this for whatever hyperlinks you want to capture, and then close the forwarded window in your AOL.